# Wizard will not create a update statement in the table adapter

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset

The wizard will not create an update statement or a delete statement. However it does an Insert command and a select command. The single table has the identity  set to yes and the Primary key is set on the table in the dataset. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` require a primary key in order to identify the record to update or delete.  If your database table has no primary key then the wizard can't create those commands.  No primary key is required for an `InsertCommand` because there's no existing record to identify.  There's rarely a good reason for a database table to not have a primary key though, so your database is probably badly designed.